# I've been reading how CORS work and tried everything that made sense, still my React/Vite App is failing to reach my express API due to CORS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors, vite

I am doing a little exercise for setting up an authentication service, the API finally seems to work, but when I try to reach it through the browser I can't get it to work. My app is running on Vite with React and the backend is made with Express. I am doing my request using Axios through an Axios Instance.
This is the codebase https://github.com/dariogliendo/mern-comuna
If you don't want to check out the whole repository (it's a pretty simple one), this is my main server code:

```
import express from 'express'
import auth from './API/auth.js'
import cors from 'cors'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(auth)
const port = 8000


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to MongoDB established')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to connect to Mongo', err)
  })
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening on ${port}`)
})
```

This is my Axios Instance code

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  }
})

export default instance
```

Here baseURL is http://localhost:8000, the URL to my express erver

and finally this is my request call in the login component

```
const token = await axiosInstance.post('/auth/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      console.log(token)
```

I've read a lot of questions and responses, tried a whole bunch of stuff, but can't get it to work. I suspect I might be lacking some understanding of how Vite works in this regards. I do not want to use a URL proxi like cors-anywhere, I would like my code to be abled to be used for production.

I've tried a lot of things, a little recap:

- Using the cors NPM package
- Setting up my headers manually
- Using route-specific headers
- Specifying Content-Type client-side
- Setting up a proxy for the Vite dev-server (probably badly)

I expect to reach the authentication code with no CORS error

Comment: Can you share the complete error message? A screenshot or copied text will do.

Comment: You need to amend your CORS configuration to 1) allow credentials, 2) allow request header `Content-Type`, and 3) allow the specific origin of your client. See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors